# Recent Screen not working after accidentally uninstalling System Launcher on Vivo Y20i

Tags: recents-screen, vivo, gestures

I am removing some bloatware apps in my Vivo Y20i because it is getting slow and lagging too much, storage space is not an issue but the RAM consumption of default apps that I can't uninstall is too high. So I resulted in looking up a method to uninstall that bloatware, and I found a method using Shizuku and aShell. I have success in removing most apps but I accidentally included the System Launcher to uninstall (I'm using Nova Launcher as default btw). Now I'm having an issue with my navigation controls where the recent app button/gesture is not working anymore, the home and back button works fine.

I tried installing some navigation controls from the Play Store and also used the gesture functions of Nova Launcher but still, it doesn't help.

Hoping someone can help me, thank you in advance.